# make_pair for vector<vector<struct>>

Tags: c++, vector

I have file in this format:

```
id1   its_vlaue1   id2   its_vlaue2   id3   its_vlaue3 
id4   its_vlaue4   id5   its_vlaue5
id6   its_vlaue6   id7   its_vlaue7   id8   its_vlaue8
```

where id is integer, and its_vlaue is float, for example:

```
100 0.1 2 0.6 9 0.03
4 0.6 3 0.1
.
.
until 300k line
```

I read this file as:

```
struct dataf
{
    int id;
    float value;
};
vector<vector<dataf>> mydata;  
dataf DF; 

void main()
{

    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("MyData.txt");
    if (inFile.fail())
        cout << "\n The file has been not found, please try again \n ";
    else
    {
        string line;
        cout << "\n File found!\n Reading the file data! \n\n";

        // Read the file until EOF

        while (!inFile.eof())
        {           
            getline(inFile, line); 
            std::stringstream Sline(line); 

            while (Sline >> DF.id>> DF.value)
            {               
                vector<dataf>  temp;
                temp.push_back(DF);
                mydata.push_back(temp); 
            }

        }

    }
    inFile.close();

    PairS();

    cout << " \nPress any key to continue\n";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();

    return;
}
```

**PairS() function make_pair such that:**

```
(id1,id2), (id1,id3), (id2,id3)
(id4,id5)
(id6,id7), (id6,id8), (id7,id8)
```

but, i couldn't figure it out

```
void PairS()
    {
        vector<dataf>::iterator i;
        vector<dataf>::iterator j;
           std::map<std::pair< int, int>, float> Pairf;

        for (int k = 0; k != ((mydata.size()) - 1); ++k)
        {

        for (i = mydata[k].begin(); i != mydata[k].end(); ++i)
        {
            int a = (*i).Item;

            for (j = mydata[k + 1].begin(); j != mydata[k+1].end(); ++j)
            {

                int b =(*j).Item;
                auto itt = Pairf.find(std::make_pair(b, a));
                ++Pairf[(itt != Pairf.end()) ? std::make_pair(b, a) : std::make_pair(a, b)];

            }

        }
        }

        cout << "\n\n The TotalSupp's Count for every Pair of Items :\n\n";
        for (const auto& p : Pairf)
        {
            std::cout << "(" << p.first.first << " " << p.first.second << ") = "
                << p.second << '\n';
        }

        cout << "\n";

}
```

also, I'm not sure if I did choose the suitable method for storing my data in vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part (just reading data from a file), I'd probably do something like this:

```
struct dataf
{
    int id;
    float value;

    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, dataf &d) { 
        return is >> d.id >> d.value;
    }
};

// ...

std::ifstream in("yourfile.dat");

// read data from file to vector
std::vector<dataf> data{std::istream_iterator<dataf>(in),
                        std::istream_iterator<dataf>()};
```

At least if I'm reading your `PairS` correctly, you seem to want only unique items. If you want (or at least don't object to) the data being sorted in the process, you can remove duplicates a little more easily like this:

```
std::sort(data.begin(), data.end());
data.erase(std::unique(data.begin(), data.end()), data.end());
```

If you need to maintain the original order, you can do something like this:

```
std::unordered_set unique;
std::vector<dataf> data;

std::copy_if(std::istream_iterator<dataf>(in),
             std::istream_iterator<dataf>,
             std::back_inserter(data),
             [&](dataf const &d) { return unique.insert(d).second; });
```

The basic idea here is that as each item is read, it attempts to insert that item into the `unordered_set`. We copy if to the vector iff that succeeds, which indicates that it hasn't been seen previously.

Comment: Thanks a lot. the first part work, but I have question: the code that when you read data from file, in means all data? and () means until the end of file?

Comment: the second part, gave me errors, so I didn't test it, even after I insert ( #include<string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <algorithm> )

Comment: for the second part, I want make_pair with items in the vector, such that all the items in the first line will be: (id1,id2), (id1,id3), (id2,id3) and count their frequencies, and do the same for the second line:  (id4,id5), if a pair is exist in line, I will not create pair instead, i will update its frequency. I guess i will try to do that from the file immediately instead of putting my data in vector first